# Custom Daemon Rails 4 Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, daemon

I need something sending emails on demand.

Each user in my app should be able to set a date and hour when he will receive an email periodically, reminding that she or him has to take medicines.

Is it possible to handle this with a custom daemon? I think so, but its my first time with this stuff and I need your opinion to be sure before starting.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/129-custom-daemon

Thanks a lot, guys.

Edit:

medicine_worker.rb:

```
class MedicineWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(name, count)
    puts 'Doing hard work'
  end

end
```

redis.rb:

```
# bundle exec sidekiq
$redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)
```

bundle exec sidekiq:

```
2014-08-26T14:57:17.321Z 1754 TID-znnu9k INFO: Running in ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
2014-08-26T14:57:17.321Z 1754 TID-znnu9k INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2014-08-26T14:57:17.321Z 1754 TID-znnu9k INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org/pro
2014-08-26T14:57:17.321Z 1754 TID-znnu9k INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
2014-08-26T14:57:17.374Z 1754 TID-zvhqi8 MedicineWorker JID-d3b450f5fd4b926ea70f1c13 INFO: start
Doing hard work
2014-08-26T14:57:17.374Z 1754 TID-zvgu8k MedicineWorker JID-f4958c2fb72aabd91d53b02b INFO: start
Doing hard work
2014-08-26T14:57:17.375Z 1754 TID-zvgbmk MedicineWorker JID-104ee301c6e5a034f42ed06d INFO: start
Doing hard work2014-08-26T14:57:17.375Z 1754 TID-zvfigk MedicineWorker JID-5698a08a24a3def961908dc1 INFO: start

Doing hard work2014-08-26T14:57:17.376Z 1754 TID-zt4ps4 MedicineWorker JID-36d06312e1fdfe8cc439ddbd INFO: start
Doing hard work
2014-08-26T14:57:17.377Z 1754 TID-zvgu8k MedicineWorker JID-f4958c2fb72aabd91d53b02b INFO: done: 0.003 sec

2014-08-26T14:57:17.378Z 1754 TID-zt3qkc MedicineWorker JID-b25e0e7be05580e358c6744a INFO: start
Doing hard work
2014-08-26T14:57:17.379Z 1754 TID-zvhqi8 MedicineWorker JID-d3b450f5fd4b926ea70f1c13 INFO: done: 0.005 sec
2014-08-26T14:57:17.380Z 1754 TID-zvgbmk MedicineWorker JID-104ee301c6e5a034f42ed06d INFO: done: 0.005 sec
2014-08-26T14:57:17.380Z 1754 TID-zvgqac MedicineWorker JID-38a185bc67c673062c475faf INFO: start
Doing hard work2014-08-26T14:57:17.380Z 1754 TID-zvhbbk MedicineWorker JID-d2058fcebd88210c406b49e4 INFO: start

Doing hard work2014-08-26T14:57:17.383Z 1754 TID-zt4ps4 MedicineWorker JID-36d06312e1fdfe8cc439ddbd INFO: done: 0.007 sec

2014-08-26T14:57:17.384Z 1754 TID-zvfigk MedicineWorker JID-5698a08a24a3def961908dc1 INFO: done: 0.009 sec
2014-08-26T14:57:17.385Z 1754 TID-zvf9k0 MedicineWorker JID-cc5e3ee8ddeead76d0c1fc5b INFO: start
Doing hard work2014-08-26T14:57:17.385Z 1754 TID-zvg6c0 MedicineWorker JID-d83dc9cb10b69c1680305417 INFO: start
Doing hard work

2014-08-26T14:57:17.385Z 1754 TID-zt4h14 MedicineWorker JID-9d13fbed1bb0042eea452ec5 INFO: start
Doing hard work
2014-08-26T14:57:17.388Z 1754 TID-zt5uv0 MedicineWorker JID-877e16ded3e18828e3396719 INFO: start
Doing hard work2014-08-26T14:57:17.389Z 1754 TID-zt3qkc MedicineWorker JID-b25e0e7be05580e358c6744a INFO: done: 0.011 sec

2014-08-26T14:57:17.389Z 1754 TID-10h4kzs MedicineWorker JID-6739ea8a340b44c06da9dabf INFO: start
Doing hard work
2014-08-26T14:57:17.390Z 1754 TID-10h4pi0 MedicineWorker JID-dcb9282efabb6c9948014834 INFO: start
Doing hard work
2014-08-26T14:57:17.391Z 1754 TID-zt1wnk MedicineWorker JID-c6fa12391faff774ffda3f5b INFO: start
Doing hard work
2014-08-26T14:57:17.392Z 1754 TID-10h6pco MedicineWorker JID-44d7747775163b4f8bf40af8 INFO: start
Doing hard work
2014-08-26T14:57:17.393Z 1754 TID-10h6u2o MedicineWorker JID-212baee3c6f3526a3ff24d9c INFO: start
Doing hard work
2014-08-26T14:57:17.394Z 1754 TID-10h5cvo MedicineWorker JID-27f2009864a0e63ab4cab2d3 INFO: start
Doing hard work2014-08-26T14:57:17.446Z 1754 T
```

.......
.......
.......

Answer (score 0):

You better use a Background Queue for this preferably one with a scheduling option.

Sidekiq is pretty good for what you need.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs

Comment: Thanks Serdar! Im working with Sidekiq. My poroblem is tha im getting an infinite loop when I just try to reproduce the very simple example in http://sidekiq.org/. Aaaaaagggg!! Any idea?

Comment: There doesnt seem to be an infinite loop in your log. How do you call the Sidekiq jobs ?

Comment: I mean that if for instance I try to send an email each hour with something like this: UserEmail.delay_for(1.hour).medicine_reminder_email() I recevie 60 or more emails in just a moment.